# Limit sum of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, limit, rows

I want to limit the sum of `product_` in columns `p_description`, `p_reference = 1A00001` and only show rows that give us a total `p_quanity` <= 21000.

Here is the design of the product_table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_table` (
  `p_id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `p_description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `p_reference` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_location` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `product_table` (`p_id`, `p_description`, `p_reference`, `p_location`, `p_quantity`) VALUES
(1, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'AP07', 7000),
(2, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'AF05', 6000),
(3, 'Product_1', '1A00233', 'DS07', 7000),
(4, 'Product_1', '1A00233', 'SD10', 5000),
(5, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'YB12', 7000),
(6, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'AN01', 7000),
(7, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'AP04', 7000),
(8, 'Product_1', '1A00245', 'AP01', 7000),
(9, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'QD01', 7000),
(10, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'SC01', 7000);
```

Comment: The question isn't too clear (at least not to me). Could you add the output you're trying to get?

Comment: My only question is whether OP needs *any* group of rows that meet the criteria, or *all possible* groupings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a running total variable, like this:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT p_id, p_description, (@runtot := @runtot + p_quantity) AS runningTotal
FROM product_table
WHERE @runtot + p_quantity <= 21000 AND p_reference = '1A00001';
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65b32e/4). This will only return the first rows found that fulfill this, it doesn't return every grouping of rows that can achieve this. If all you're looking for though are any three rows that satisfy this, it should work just fine.